# Integer vs. int comparison

Tags: java, integer, boxing, autoboxing

I am new to `java`. I am now learning the non-primitive Integer type in `java`. 
I know the following comparison is not valid and throws a compilation error -

```
String str = "c";
Char chr = 'c';
if(str == chr) return true;
```

The above code snippet gives me the  - "Test.java:lineNumber: incomparable types: java.lang.String and char" errors.

But I found the following code snippet compiles fine -

```
int a = 1234;
Integer aI = 1234;
if(a==aI) return true;
```

Here, `a` is primitive int and `aI` is non-primitive. So how they are comparable? I am new to programming, may be is there any thing I don't know.

Thanks

Comment: Boxing - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: Sidenote: the "proper" way of creating an `Integer` would be `Integer aI = new Integer(1234);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called `unboxing`. Here aI is non-primitive/reference type. Here Integer is an wrapper of primitive int. Its gives some extra easy to use manipulations over primitive int. Each primitive type for example (**boolean, byte, char, short, int, long, float, double**) has a corresponding wrapper type (**Boolean, Byte, Character, Short, Integer, Long, Float, Double**).

So when `a` is compared with `aI`, first `aI` is unboxed and become a primitive int and it's value is compared with the primitive int. That means it is equivalent to -

```
int a = 1234;
Integer aI = 1234;
int a2 = aI.intValue();
if(a == a2) return true;
```

And for the first comparison the comparison occurred between completely two different data types - `String` and `char`. In this case there is no rule defined in java to convert `char` to `String` or `String` to `char` by default.

Answer (score 4):

The second snippet demonstrates an unboxing conversion.  Boxing conversion allows a primitive type to be converted implicitly to a specific object wrapper type, e.g. `int` <-> `Integer`.

When comparing with the `==` operator, if one operand is a primitive type and the other is such a wrapper type, an unboxing conversion is performed so the 2 primitive values can be compared.

The first snippet doesn't compile because there is no boxing/unboxing relationship between `String` and `char` -- the relevant relationship is `Character` <-> `char`.

[Section 5.1.8 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) specifies all unboxing conversions:

> - From type Boolean to type boolean
> - From type Byte to type byte
> - From type Short to type short
> - From type Character to type char
> - From type Integer to type int
> - From type Long to type long
> - From type Float to type float
> - From type Double to type double

[Section 5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) specifies all boxing conversions, all of which are the reverse of the above.

Answer (score 0):

In first case the two data type are different. So they can not be compared.
And in second case, the two data type also different, but the wrapper `Integer` is made to support primitive `int`. So JVM automatically done the conversion of wrapper (unboxing) `Integer` to `int` and then compare. So actually in the second case two primitive `int` are compared to each other at the end.