# Comparing an int and Integer in Java

Tags: java

Consider the following snippet:

```
Integer Foo = 2;
int foo = 1;
boolean b = Foo < foo;
```

is `<` done using `int` or `Integer`? What about `==`?

Comment: both are done using `int`

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352791/why-comparing-integer-with-int-can-throw-nullpointerexception-in-java or http://stackoverflow.com/q/7672317/1743880. Even better http://stackoverflow.com/q/9150446/1743880. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572567/integer-vs-int-comparison

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all the relational operators (including therefore `<` and `==`), if one type is the boxed analogue of the other, then the boxed type is converted to the unboxed form.

So your code is equivalent to `Foo.intValue() < foo;`. This is deeper than you might think: your `Foo < foo` *will* throw a `NullPointerException` if `Foo` is `null`.

Answer (score 3):

According to JLS, 15.20.1

> The type of each of the operands of a numerical comparison operator must be a
>   type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs. Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).

Further, 5.6.2 states that

> If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion

This explains what is happening in your program: the `Integer` object is unboxed before the comparison is performed.

Answer (score 2):

They will be done using `int` due to [Autoboxing and Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: This is also a useful resource 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647407/why-do-we-use-autoboxing-and-unboxing-in-java

Answer (score 0):

The Wrapper types for primitive types in java does automatic "type casting" ( or autoboxing / unboxing)  from Object to compatible primitive type. so Integer will be converted to int before passing it to comparison operators or arithmetic operators like < , > , == , = , + and - etc.